# Android - How to change menu item icon when clicked

Tags: android

I currently have one item in my menu which is an icon of a pig. What I would like to happen is when I click on the pig, the icon will then change to another image like a chicken. I've read other forums on StackOverFlow but still no luck.

I know you cannot use findViewbyId to reference a menu Item but the findItem method is not working for me or at least it says invalid. Please advise.

Here is my current code:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/menuImage"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/pig"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
    </menu>


    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menuImage:
            Toast.makeText(this, "YOU THINK YOU GOT THIS?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            MenuItem changeImage = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.menuImage);
            changeImage.setIcon(R.drawable.chicken);
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onOptionsItemSelected` is called whenever an item in your options menu is selected. 
The `item` parameter contains the menu item that was selected.

So you can do this:

```
item.setIcon(R.drawable.chicken);
```

Comment: @ojboba we all been there